# VB.NET: Resize an image (jpg,gif,png) to avoid out of memory error in Picturebox Control on .NETCF 2.0

Tags: vb.net, image, compact-framework, picturebox, resize

I'm searching for a solution to resize image(jpg) being passed in from an array in Picturebox Control on .NETCF 2.0 in VB.NET without resorting to using the opennetcf library, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the image into a thumbnail with [IImage::GetThumbnail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa918965.aspx).  This is done using the Imaging library via P/Invoke. The Smart Device Framework [has this done](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/36134/1954), but the original question is asking for advice on how to do it without the SDF.  Without is a bit more complex as you're going to have to deal with writing the proxy wrapper classes.